# RecyclerView holder always is wrap_content

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have this layout with a recyclerview:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context=".view.ContactFragment">

<data>

    <variable
        name="vm"
        type="corp.br.UserInfoViewModel" />


</data>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:padding="@dimen/default_margin"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/account_destination_label"
        android:id="@+id/accountDestinationTv"
        style="@style/DefaulAppearance.Title"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/contactsRv"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/default_margin"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/accountDestinationTv"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

And I have this holder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context=".adapter.holder.BaseHolder">

<data>
    <variable
        name="name"
        type="String" />
</data>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/item_contact_name"
    android:text="@{name}"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="@dimen/default_margin"
    style="@style/DefaulAppearance"
    tools:text="teste"
    />

</layout>
```

By some reason every holder item has the wrap_content property when I use Layout Inspector and click only works when I click over the text and not in the entire line. My fragment that have this recyclerview doesn't do any change to the size, neighter the adapter and viewholder do.

Someone can tell me what is wrong?

Comment: I see your answer below, but that should not be necessary. I suspect that you are not inflating your viewholder's item view correctly. It should look like `inflate(R.layout.foo, parent, false)` and not like `inflate(R.layout.foo, null)`. Is this the problem?

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution... the problem was about the LinearLayoutManager.

the default LinearLayoutManager code that was causing my problem:

```
@Override
public RecyclerView.LayoutParams generateDefaultLayoutParams() {
    return new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
}
```

the solution that I applied in my fragment:

```
bind.contactsRv.layoutManager = object : LinearLayoutManager(this@ContactFragment.context) {
        override fun generateDefaultLayoutParams(): RecyclerView.LayoutParams {
            return RecyclerView.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
        }
    }
```

I just override the `ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT` by `ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT` in the first parameter of LayoutParams